# ${z_n}$ is a geometric sequence, $z_1=1, z_2=a+bi, z_3=b+ai$, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $a>0$. What is the smallest $n$ s.t. $z_1+z_2+...+z_n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> ${z_n}$ is a geometric sequence, $z_1=1, z_2=a+bi, z_3=b+ai$, $a$ and
>   $b$ are real numbers, $a>0$. What is the smallest $n$ such that
>   $z_1+z_2+...+z_n=0$?

So far I found out that $r=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, but I don't know how to find the smallest $n$ such that $z_1+z_2+...+z_n=0$. I tried using the geometric series formula and got:

$\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^n}{1-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)}=0$, and from here multiplied both sides by ${1-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)}$ to get $1-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^n=0$, and then moved one to the other side, got rid of the negatives, and took the n root of both sides. But, then I got: $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. So, I don't know if I messed up or if there's no solution.

Comment: What makes you to think $r=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i?$

Comment: $(a+bi)^2=b+ai$, solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: actually nvm, $r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i$, I believe. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I think you have calculated $r$ incorrectly. Based on what you have 
$$z_3=rz_2=r^2 \implies b+ai=(a+ib)^2.$$
This gives:
\begin{align*}
b&=a^2-b^2\\
a&=2ab.
\end{align*}
Solving this gives us either the zero solution or $a=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $\color{red}{r=\frac{\pm\sqrt{3}+i}{2}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}} \text{ or } e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}}$

For the first value $r=e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$. So,
\begin{align*}
z_1+z_2+\dotsb+z_n&=1+r+r^2+\dotsb+r^n\\
&=\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}.
\end{align*}
For this to be zero, we need
$$r^{n}=1 \implies e^{i\frac{n\pi}{6}}=1.$$

Comment: Yes, I just realized my mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: Absolutely correct resolution, minor point (that changes the answer): Since $z_1 = 1$, we have $z_1 + z_2 + \ldots + z_n$ = $1 + r + \ldots + r ^{n-1}$, so we have $n$ and not $n+1$ in the final equation.

Comment: @PedroM. Thanks for pointing the error. I have fixed the exponent.